# Dot Net Nuke Ajax Response Returning HTML

Tags: ajax, dotnetnuke

I can't seem to get a JSON response from an Ajax post within a Dot Net Nuke site. It returns HTML as a response instead.

I was able to get this to work in a normal test site just fine and am wondering if anybody may know what I need to do.

Below is the code I'm testing with for now:

JavaScript:

```
$("#ClearTaxFormButton").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var testValue = 7;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "localhost/mywebsite/tabid/100/Default.aspx/SumbitByAjaxTest",
            data: '{ "taxRate":' + testValue + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                //$("#Result").text(msg.d);
                alert(msg.d);
            }
        });
    });
```

C# Function:

```
//just using ths for testing
[WebMethod]
public static string SumbitByAjaxTest(string taxRate)
{
    return taxRate;
}
```

Like I said, this exact code (aside from a different URL) works fine in a normal .NET site but when I move it over to the Dot Net Nuke site, it returns HTML.

Any ideas??

Comment: Is it returning HTML or XML?

Comment: it is returning html. It is just rendering the html of the page itself

Comment: That is because DNN doesn't handle webrequests in that manner, that is just another URL to DNN so it responds with a page. You'll need to create a service to get this going (as noted below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNN's service layer allows you to follow a Webapi like approach, I think you'll find that easier for controlling the data to/from.

Here's an example of a controller for an open source articles module
https://dnnsimplearticle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#cs/services/DnnSimpleArticleController.cs

Something like

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetAllArticles(int portalId, bool sortAsc)
        {
            try
            {
                //todo: get the latest X articles?
                var articles = ArticleController.GetAllArticles(portalId, sortAsc);

                //because of the circular reference when cerealizing the taxonomy within content items we have to build out our article view models manually.
                var cleanArticles = new List<ArticleViewModel>();
                foreach (Article a in articles)
                {
                    var newArt = new ArticleViewModel
                    {
                        ArticleId = a.ArticleId,
                        Body = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(a.Body),
                        CreatedByUser = a.CreatedByUser,
                        CreatedByUserId = a.CreatedByUserId,
                        CreatedOnDate = a.CreatedOnDate,
                        Description = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(a.Description),
                        LastModifiedByUser = a.LastUpdatedByUser,
                        LastModifiedByUserId = a.LastModifiedByUserId,
                        LastModifiedOnDate = a.LastModifiedOnDate,
                        ModuleId = a.ModuleId,
                        Title = a.Title,
                        url = DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(a.TabID, "", "&aid=" + a.ArticleId)
                    };
                    cleanArticles.Add(newArt);
                }

                var articleViewModels = new ArticleViewModels
                {
                    Articles = cleanArticles
                };

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, articles);

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                DnnLog.Error(exc); //todo: obsolete
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "error in request"); //todo: probably should localize that?
            }
        }
```